# Search Engine Friendly Url but URL should NOT be inserted in the DB

Tags: php, joomla, sef, joomla-sef-urls

I have a Search Page and I'd like to have an SEF URL but I don't want to have it inserted in the DB.
Eg.
www.abc.com/facility-search/types/state/city/

www.abc.com/facility-search/school/california/los-angeles/
or 
www.abc.com/facility-search/school+hospital/california/los-angeles/
where the type is delimited using '+'

There are thousands of combination so I don't want to index them in the db
Is there a way to do this without the SH404SEF inserting them to the db?

I want to be able to paste the url to a browser and then just parse anything that comes after facility-search. (i wont have an equivalent url with parameters)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse. you could use `.htaccess` for a `QSA` Query apending string. So in your given example this would be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^facility-search/(.*)$ index.php?search=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and you can than catch it in your php to perform actions strip them down or anything else so catch it as:

```
$pathArray = explode('/', $_GET['rt']);
```

Now you exploded it you can do anything you like with it. The url: `www.abc.com/facility-search/school/california/los-angeles/` will give the following output

```
$pathArray[0]; // returns 'school'
$pathArray[1]; // returns 'california'
$pathArray[2]; // returns 'los-angeles'
```

I hope you understand the concept.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've added the rewrite code to the .htaccess and it worked. I just have an additional question, how can I prevent the url from being inserted in the jos_redirection. I'm not very familiar with joomla and all sorry.